# Leaflet - get data from static file and API call to build a choropleth map

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, leaflet, choropleth

I got 2 data sources with JSON data.
One is a static file and contains country borders like this:

**Static file**

```
var worldboundaries = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":

[{"type":"Feature","id":"ALB","properties":{"name":"Albania"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[20.590247,41.855404],[20.463175,41.515089],[20.605182,41.086226],[21.02004,40.842727],[20.99999,40.580004],[20.674997,40.435],[20.615,40.110007],[20.150016,39.624998],[19.98,39.694993],[19.960002,39.915006],[19.406082,40.250773],[19.319059,40.72723],[19.40355,41.409566],[19.540027,41.719986],[19.371769,41.877548],[19.304486,42.195745],[19.738051,42.688247],[19.801613,42.500093],[20.0707,42.58863],[20.283755,42.32026],[20.52295,42.21787],[20.590247,41.855404]]]}},

{"type":"Feature","id":"ARE","properties":{"name":"United Arab Emirates"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[51.579519,24.245497],[51.757441,24.294073],[51.794389,24.019826],[52.577081,24.177439],[53.404007,24.151317],[54.008001,24.121758],[54.693024,24.797892],[55.439025,25.439145],[56.070821,26.055464],[56.261042,25.714606],[56.396847,24.924732],[55.886233,24.920831],[55.804119,24.269604],[55.981214,24.130543],[55.528632,23.933604],[55.525841,23.524869],[55.234489,23.110993],[55.208341,22.70833],[55.006803,22.496948],[52.000733,23.001154],[51.617708,24.014219],[51.579519,24.245497]]]}},

....
```

and one contains the density information for fillColor which should be used for this country, where "count" is the value I need. This a kimonolabs api and called with an $AJAX request:

**API answer**

```
{"name":"myapi","count":51,"frequency":"Daily","version":109,"newdata":true,"lastrunstatus":"success","thisversionstatus":"success","nextrun":"Fri Sep 25 2015 11:29:40 GMT+0000 (UTC)","thisversionrun":"Thu Sep 24 2015 11:29:40 GMT+0000 (UTC)",

"results":

{"myapi":[{"name":{"href":"http://www.somelink.com","text":"Albania"},"count":"1","index":1,"url":"http://www.somelink.com"},

{"name":{"http://www.somelink.com","text":"United Arab Emirates"},"count":"30","index":2,"url":"http://www.somelink.com"},

...
```

For the map I'm following this guide: [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)

**JS file including API call**

```
//Building the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {
    id: 'mapbox.light',
    attribution: ...
}).addTo(map);

//Color function
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}

//Style function
function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

//Load static file
L.geoJson(worldBoundaries, {style: style}).addTo(map);

//AJAX call to API
$.ajax({
    "url":"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/myapi,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    //Make a call to the Kimono API following the "url" 

    'success': function(response){ 
    //Do some stuff, place some markers

     var collection = response.results.myapi;
     //collection.count is what I need from here

     ......
```

**EDIT**

Added a plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/98OiwqYBr7pP478tJAtl?p=preview

`getColor(feature.properties.density)` is essentially my problem. Leaflet draws the country border layer correctly but the "density" information comes from an ajax api call and is not included in the wordlboundaries array. *How can I tell it to look at the api results and using the "count" value for the correct country to color the map appropriately?* How can I access the variables from the ajax call later in another function/do I have to put every function from this into the ajax call?
Country Border file contains all countries of the world where the api request does not contain all countries.
Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues that need to be worked out before you can use the data successfully. These will be clearer if you log your data to the console to see what you're working with. Try placing the following in your AJAX success function somewhere after you've defined your boundaries layer:

```
console.log(response);
console.log(loadboundaries);
```

First of all, you will see that the API is returning data in German. There is no field called `response.results.beerorigin` (as your script is looking for), but instead one called `response.results.bierherkunft`. The count data are in a field called `response.results.bierherkunft[i].count` (where i is an object index from 0-52), and the country names are in `response.results.bierherkunft[i].name.text`.

Which brings us to the second problem: the country names returned by the API are also in German, while your GeoJSON file contains country names in English. So if you want to match up the countries in the two files, you will need to either get a GeoJSON file with country names already in German or manually translate the names in the GeoJSON file (or, perhaps better, add a new property like `name_de` to hold the translated names, in case you still have use for those English names). Of course, if there is an option to request data from the API in English, that would be the easiest solution to that problem.

Once you have all the data in the same language, you will need to join the beer data with your `loadboundaries` layer by name. This can be done by using `onEachFeature` when you create the layer to call a function that searches for a match between `feature.properties.name_de` and `response.results.bierherkunft[i].name.text`, then adds a new property for the count data. So assuming you have assigned `response.results.bierherkunft` to `collection`, it would go something like:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    feature.properties.density = 0;
    for (var i in collection) {
        if(collection[i].name.text === feature.properties.name_de) {
            feature.properties.density = parseInt(collection[i].count);
        }
    }
}
```

The `parseInt` is necessary because the `count` field is stored as text, and `getColor` is expecting a number. Applying the style can be done using the `setStyle` method, like so:

```
var loadboundaries = L.geoJson(worldboundaries, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature});

map.on('load', loadboundaries.addTo(map).setStyle(function (feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  };
}));
```

There is a working plunk here:

http://embed.plnkr.co/Qh1PKJS0Jxflc0JZ2qt4/preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right, the languages are a mess. I will add a `name_de` field for the country names. Seems like `onEachFeature` is what I'm looking for. I would call it like this `var loadboundaries = L.geoJson(worldboundaries, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature});`, right? Don't this function has to have a `return` value? I will play with it and update the plunker later (forgot to set this to public).

Comment: Updated plunk, added function and `name_de` for 2 countries to test it. If I do `console.log(feature.properties.density);` inside the `onEachFeature` function I get `undefined`. How can I pass this variable to the onEachFeature function?

Comment: Ah, just realized it's a little trickier, because the `style` function gets called before the `onEachFeature` function, so there is no `density` property at that point. Solution is probably to either add the density data before calling `L.geoJson` or use the `.setStyle` method after the fact. Will have a look and update my answer later.